# Quaternion Camera turns around on the "target axis"

Tags: c++, opengl, camera, quaternions, glm-math

I'm developping a 2D/3D Game Engine, available there: https://github.com/crakouille/ngengine

The Library 3D Camera Class is defined in include/video/D3/camera/camera.h

I store the vectors needed in gluLookAt:

```
glm::vec3 _position;
glm::vec3 _target;
glm::vec3 _normal;
```

In examples/05_3D a FreeFly Camera implementation is written (extanding the Library 3D Camera), spheric coordinates are used. It works well.

In examples/06_CameraQuat another FreeFly Camera implementation is written, with Quaternions. And my problem is there.

When I rotate around on an Axis, it works well, but when I rotate around on two Axis (by doing circles with the mouse) then the camera rotates around on the target axis and it's a problem.

Without bug (05_3D example):

[image: Without bug (05_3D example)]

With the bug of the target axis rotation (06_CameraQuat).

[image: With a bug(06_CameraQuat)]

Here is the code of the Camera:

FreeFly.h:

```
class FreeFly : public nge::video::D3::Camera {

  public:

    ...

    void rotateForward(double angle); // rotate around on the forward axis
    void rotateLeft(double angle); // rotate around on the left axis
    void rotateNormal(double angle); // rotate around on the normal axis

  private:

    void updateVectRel(); // update _targetRel, _leftRel and _normalRel

    glm::quat _quat; // the quaternion which contains the rotations

    glm::vec3 _targetRel; // the target vector, normalized, relative to _position
    glm::vec3 _leftRel; // the left vector, normalized
    glm::vec3 _normalRel; // the normal vector (up), normalized
};
```

FreeFly.cpp:

```
#include <06_CameraQuat/FreeFly.h>
#include <glm/gtx/quaternion.hpp>

......

void FreeFly::rotateForward(double angle)
{
  glm::quat q2 = glm::angleAxis((float) -angle, _targetRel);
  q2 = glm::normalize(q2);

  // q2 represents the rotation around the forward axis

  _quat = _quat * q2; // adding the rotation to _quat

  this->updateVectRel(); // updating the vectors

}

void FreeFly::rotateLeft(double angle)
{
  // idem with left axis
  glm::quat q2 = glm::angleAxis((float) -angle, _leftRel);
  q2 = glm::normalize(q2);
  _quat = _quat * q2;//glm::cross(_quat, q2);

  this->updateVectRel();
}

void FreeFly::rotateNormal(double angle)
{
  // idem with normal axis
  glm::quat q2 = glm::angleAxis((float) -angle, _normalRel);
  _quat = _quat * q2; //glm::cross(_quat, q2);

  this->updateVectRel();
}

void FreeFly::updateVectRel()
{ 
  _targetRel = glm::dvec3(1., 0., 0.);
  _leftRel = glm::dvec3(0., -1., 0.);
  _normalRel = glm::dvec3(0., 0., 1.);

  _quat = glm::normalize(_quat);

  _targetRel =  _targetRel * _quat;
  _leftRel = _leftRel * _quat;
  _normalRel = _normalRel * _quat;

  _target = _position + _targetRel;
  _normal = _normalRel;
}
```

EDIT:

Why does my Camera rotates around on the target axis ?

Note:
When I do circles with the mouse in the clockwise/anticlockwise direction, the rotation around the target axis is in the clockwise/anticlockwise direction too, respectively.

Comment: Why does my Camera rotates around on the target axis ? I would like this implementation to work as the spheric coordinates do.

Comment: Edit the question and add the question. Also, including less code and more explanations about what you have done could be usefull.

Comment: I've modified my post, erased some code, and commented it.